# Cannot add my custom performance counter in Performance Monitor

Tags: performancecounter, system-administration

My own performance monitor is created and can be seen in "Add counters" left pane's list in Performance Monitor, but I can't add it to line view, I've tried:

1. restart computer and restart Performance Monitor under Administrator priviledge
2. start service "Performance Counter DLL Host" [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208385/why-cant-perfmon-see-instances-of-my-custom-performance-counter)
3. add current windows account to Performance Monitor Users local group [ref](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c06618e-65ca-40e6-b5e0-01dbd0548c8b/cannot-see-the-custom-performance-counters-for-a-web-application-added-in-applicationinsightsconfig?forum=ApplicationInsights)
4. rebuild performance monitor and make sure my custom performance monitor is enabled [ref](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/perfmon-problems-unable-to-add-counters/e90f231d-0014-457d-8b1f-5f342971597a)

but I still cannot add it to the line view, while other system's own counter can

Does anyone has any clue please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own.. I realized the Event Viewer might help so I checked it, among all the add counter operations, an error appears once with the message being "Disabled performance counter data collection from the "ASP.NET_2.0.50727" service because the performance counter library for that service has generated one or more errors. The errors that forced this action have been written to the application event log. Correct the errors before enabling the performance counters for this service." so I googled this message and found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0a4fce81-89a6-4267-9343-3f09dd0aeee3/perflib-complaining-about-32bit-aspnet-dll-in-64bit-environment), I followed the steps answered by "Nick Gu - MSFT" and it worked! The counter can be added now.